# Pair key-value for filter using ag-grid

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-valuesetter

Are there any form to set pair key-values for the filter in ag-grid? (show to the user a different value than it is set in the filterModel)

```
filterParams: {
    values: { tyt: "Toyota",
         frd: "Ford",
         prs: "Porsche",
          nss: "Nissan"
     },
}
```

```
filterParams: {
    values: ["Toyota", "Ford", "Porsche", "Nissan"],
    cellRendererParams: return 'tyt',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set a customize filter using a framework component, something similar that they use here( partialMatchFilter.js), changing the template.
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#accessing-the-vuejs-component-instance